# Rename the tag [quarks] to [apache-edgent]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[Quarks](http://quarks-edge.github.io/) was submitted to the ASF as "Apache Quarks" and was subsequently incubated and renamed "[Apache Edgent](http://edgent.apache.org)". The [quarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarks) tag's description needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: It seems like this was done, there're no tag `quarks` by now, only `apache-edgent`

Comment: Since there were only 3 [tag:quarks] questions when this retag request was made, I moved them to the new tag [tag:apache-edgent].